# Restrict viewing/listing objects in S3 with a specific prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I've got a bucket policy to restrict roles (apart from one) from downloading/putting objects of a specific name into my S3 bucket.

However I'm having difficulty restricting the file from even being viewed if the file is there.

I would like to restrict roles from even listing files in the bucket with a prefix of 'audit'. I would still like them to be able to list all other objects in the path.

So far I've tried a few variations of this bucket policy. The role ID is for the role that *should* be able to view the files

```
- Sid: 3
        Effect: Deny
        Principal: "*"
        Action: 
          - s3:ListBucket
        Resource: 
          - arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/audit*
        Condition:
          StringNotLike:
            aws:userid:
              - <THE ALLOWED ROLE ID>:*
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement 
(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; 
Error Code: MalformedPolicy; Request ID:
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you confirmed that the arn in the resources is your buckets arn?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Yes, it's definitely the same, I've got other policy statements with the same resource and they're all working

Comment: The error message is 100% accurate, but a lot of people misunderstand it. It means that `s3:ListBucket` is an action that is not possible against the resource `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/audit*` because the action applies to an S3 bucket but the resource you indicated represents S3 objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aws:PrincipalArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html) condition to check for the IAM ARN.

> Works with ARN operators and string operators.

> Use this key to compare the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the principal that made the request with the ARN that you specify in the policy. For IAM roles, the request context returns the ARN of the role, not the ARN of the user that assumed the role. To learn which types of principals you can specify in this condition key, see Specifying a principal.

> Availability – This key is always included in the request context.

```json
{
  "Statement": [
    {  "Sid": "1",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ArnNotLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": [
            "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/myrole"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now why it is saying `invalid` policy because [s3:ListBucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) permission deals with bucket, not at the object level, so you are getting the error.

[s3:GetObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html) applies to the objects in the bucket so the Resource is correct:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*".
```

[s3:ListBucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) applies to the Bucket itself and so the Resource should be

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. So do you know of any way I could restrict objects with a prefix from being viewed by certain roles, but they can still list all the other objects? Thanks

Comment: @DonJuanEco yes just use with `*` with `s3:GetObject` permissions combined with. `aws:PrincipalArn` should work.